# Jquery custom rule validation on multiple controls

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I have multiple date controls on a screen which are dynamically named.

I have the following JSfiddle. I would like to know if it is possible to create a single rule for all date fields on a form

http://jsfiddle.net/bboymarko/6tyAd/1/

HTML

## Date Validation

```
<br />
<label for="date">Enter Date</label>
<input id="date" name="date" type="text" />

<br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Javascript
   $(document).ready(function () {

```
$.validator.addMethod("kdate", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\/(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\/\d{4}$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a valid date.");

$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        date: {
            required: true,
            kdate: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form'); // for demo
        return false;  // for demo
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Do you mean that you have multiple date input field in a form named like date1, date2, date3. Want to include in rules property

Comment: I want to include all the fields like date1 etc.. Im not sure if you can validate on something like a class

Comment: you can do it on an id

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can use [jQuery Date Picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) which will allow you to assign it to multiple fields and restrict/fore users to format their dates. so no messy Regular Expressions to use and it can be neater.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am using it and it will provide the correct value, but in IE it doesn't accept the correct format value and deems it invalid. The Regex is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible when you have class in place like

```
<input id="date" name="date" type="text" class="dateValidate"/>
```

and use this class selector for validating the date

```
$('.dateValidate'). whatever method you want to initialize.
```

or

Create dynamic ids as you dynamically name them

like date1 , date2 ,date3 and use a for loop

```
for(i=1;i<=size;i++){

$('#date'+i).your method

}
```